# unknown attribute error in ruby on rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have a user model and a friend model (friend inherits from user class). A user has many friends through the friendships join model.

The user can also create messages and send them to their friends. I want to be able to track which messages are sent to which friends. 
So I've created a message model which is joined with the friendships model to create the associated sent_messages model.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base  
    has_many :friendships
    has_many :friends, :through => :friendships

    has_many :messages
end

class Friendship < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :friend, :class_name => 'User'

    has_many :sent_messages
    has_many :messages, :through => :sent_messages
end

class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user

    has_many :sent_messagess
    has_many :friendships, :through => :sent_messages
end

class SentMessage < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :message
    belongs_to :friendship
end
```

In the message creation form there will be a text box for data and a checkbox listing all the friends of a user they can choose to send the message to.

```
<%= form_for @message, url: user_messages_path do |f| %>

    <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.text_field :title %>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.text_area :message %>
    </div>  

    <% Friendship.all.each do |friendship| -%>
        <div>
            <%= check_box_tag('message[friendships_id][]',friendship.id,@message.friendships.include?(friendship.id))%>
            <%= label_tag friendship.friend_username %>
        </div>
    <% end -%>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Send", class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Here is the messages controller

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController
    before_action :authenticate_user!

  def create
    @message = Message.new(message_params)
    if @message.save
        redirect_to action: "show", id: @message.id
    else
        respond_to do |format|
            format.html
            format.js
        end
    end
  end

  private

    def message_params
      params.require(:message).permit(:title,:message,:friendships_id => [])
    end
end
```

Here is the schema

```
  create_table "messages", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "message"
  end
  create_table "sent_messages", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "message_id"
    t.integer  "friendships_id"
  end
  create_table "friendships", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "friend_id"
    t.string   "friend_username"
  end
```

When I submit a message, i get the error "unknown attribute: friendships_id"
Not sure how to correct this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to pass friendships_id while creating @message, but there is not friendships_id column in messages table in your database, which is causing this error of "unknown attribute: friendships_id".

Apart from this you have a some mistakes in your associations and migration.

1. `has_many :sent_messagess` should be `has_many :sent_messages`
2. Alter your 'sent_messages' table to change column 'friendships_id' to 'friendship_id'